# NSDateFormatter to date

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Hello I've strange problem with parsing this `NSString` to `NSDate`: "`2013-05-31T11:56:07+0200`", I`ve tried:

```
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
```

but always return nil.

Comment: Show your entire code. With this dateFormat it should work.

Comment: Something else is wrong.  Are you sure you date formatter even exists?

Answer (score 1):

From the unicode date formats specified for iOS 5.1 and up these are the timezone formats

[image]

I have verified this one and it works with output **2013-05-31 09:56:07 +0000**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-05-31T11:56:07+0200"];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Comment: Hm return again nil:(

Comment: @user2429398 Can you post the entire code wrt to the conversion in your question?

Comment: Why the extra `'` character at the end??

Comment: @HotLicks That was a typo, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];

NSLog(@"\n"
      "theDate: |%@| \n"
      "theTime: |%@| \n"
      , theDate, theTime);
```